# How to find if an arbitrary linear combination can be solved with only positive constants

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a linear combination of vectors

$
\vec{b} =  c_1\vec{v_1}  + c_2 \vec{v_2} + ... + c_k \vec{v_k}
$

Where we're given numeric values for $\vec{b}$ and all vectors {$\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, ..., \vec{v_k}$}

I'd like to know two things:

1. How can I know if there exists a solution where the unknown coefficients $c_1,c_2,...,c_k$ are all positive real values?
2. If a solution exists, what is the general method to find these values?

What I've tried so far:

1. Turn it into an $A \vec{x} = \vec{b} $ type of problem, where A is the matrix of column vectors ($\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, ..., \vec{v_k}$) and $\vec{x}$ is a vector composed of unknown constants $c_1,c_2,...,c_k$ and see if there's a solution— if there isn't one, then job done it's an inconsistent system— if there's only a single solution, then that can be examined directly— but I ran into a problem when there are free variables and many possible solutions.
2. In the event that there are free variables- my approach is to make another linear combination, but this time determine if the span of this linear combination includes positive real space of whatever dimension $\vec{b}$ may be, which will then mean you can choose free variables such that all coefficients $c_1,c_2,...,c_k$ are positive.

Example. Upon solving for $A \vec{x} = \vec{b} $ you get something like-
$$\vec{x} = \vec{v_0} + x_5\vec{v_1} + x_6\vec{v_2} $$
Where $\vec{x}$ is the vector composed of acceptable $c_1,c_2,...,c_k$ , $\vec{v_0}$,$\vec{v_1}$,$\vec{v_2}$ are composed of constants, and $x_5$,$x_6$ are free variables determined from the solution attempt in 1. At this point I'm stuck because I'm not entirely sure how to find free variables that guarantee every entry in $\vec{x}$ is a positive value.

Please let me know if my approach is actually reasonable and how I would go about solving this problem. Thank you

Comment: All $c_k$ positive is a linear programming problem. Use equality constraints for $\vec{b}$. Minimize $\sum{c_k}$.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: Maybe something like considering [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) can help.

Comment: I think that firts  is neccesary know if the sistem of equations $$\vec{x}V=\vec{b}$$
With $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_k)$
and $V=(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3,\cdots,\vec{v}_k)^T$, has only one solution etc...